# Where should I store my Webauthn challenge on my server?

Tags: webauthn

I was reading about WebAuthn at https://webauthn.guide/ when I came across the text below.

```
challenge: This is the same challenge that was passed into the create() call. The server must validate that this returned challenge matches the one generated for this registration event.
```

Based on the text above, I am assuming that I will need to store the generated challenge on my server. Am I right? If yes, then where should I store the generated challenge on my server?

Answer (score 0):

That is very difficult to answer without understanding your platform's architecture. Challenges are short lived. For registration flows, you need to ensure challenges are tightly bound to the account for which the credential is being created, e.g. bound to the session.